# How do I destroy weeds?

Tags: innocent-life

Unlike Harvest Moon: Back to Nature, weeds do not get destroyed in Innocent Life when you throw it on the ground.

How can I permanently destroy weeds in Innocent Life?

Comment: In my experience, the most common method is to set it on fire.

Comment: I dont think there is a way to do it @LessPoop_MoreFritz

Comment: I believe you can throw them in the trash.  Not 100% on that, though.

Comment: This question title is under my protection.

Comment: I have failed...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An Iron Sickle destroys weeds efficiently. If you can not obtain an Iron Sickle, try throwing your weeds into the pond.